# Block break lag in single player game? (Minecraft 1.8.6)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Anyone who has played online has already experienced the block break lag. When you have slow connection, or when the server's CPU is overwhelmed, the blocks you destroy will first reappear, then later on they pop out. Sometimes, they don't actually pop out and you have to destroy them again. In multiplayer, the same thing applies to placing the blocks.

The thing is, that I experience this in single player game. It occurs randomly and as of now, I found no correlation with anything else (specific chunks, amount of mobs or entities...). Also, other things work perfectly and instantly:

- no inventory lag
- no item pickup lag
- no monster desync lag (monsters are really where I see them)

I noticed one thing that is related though:

- along with this issue, **horse-riding is as slow as walking**

So far, I have tried the following without results:

- restarting the game
- Changing version of JRE (java)
- reducing video settings. The problem doesn't reduce even if I set 2 chunk render distance

I made a youtube video which can be seen here:

Answer (score 1):

You can experience this in singleplayer because in singleplayer you are playing on the server too. When you open the game to LAN, other players can join that server. Internal servers added on Minecraft 1.3

You can try moving Minecraft directory to a faster HDD/SSD, upgrading your CPU.

Comment: Weird that you say it's caused because single player uses server too, but also say that optifine is supposed to help. Isn't optifine modifying client side only?

Comment: Yeah, my bad. But you can try others.

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to get technical, you can host a single-person dedicated server on your computer and join from that. You can use any render distance at that point, and it'll work fine.

[Here's how to set one up.](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Setting_up_a_server)

Disclaimer, it does take slightly more CPU power than just a singleplayer world, so it's a bit of a trade-off.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem on my old computer.
After I got a new one, I first started my old minecraft from a network share, and I had the same problem on my brand new computer.

After some tests I noticed, that the reason was my HDD was to old and to slow in read and write speed.
After moving my minecraft directory on a other drive, the problem was solved (even on my old computer)

Answer (score -1):

For me it was the render distance on 16 chunks that triggered that awfull delay, below 16 everything was normal, maybe it is some video setting that triggers this kind of delay.

Answer (score -2):

I suggest using a lag-reducing tool like [OptiFine](http://www.optifine.net/). The latest version (as of posting time) is compatible with Minecraft 1.8.4. Try using the settings in that to eliminate the lag.

Answer (score -3):

I do have that problem too!
I fixed it when i reinstalled the game and turned VBO´s ON!

Answer (score -3):

I had the same problem, I fixed it by making sure Minecraft ran using the 'powerful Nvidia-processor' instead of the integrated graphics

Comment: How did you do that? Please explain.